# Text pattern analysis in pig

Tags: design-patterns, apache-pig, sequential

I'm looking for a way to save text patterns using pig. Say I have an input as follows:

```
ae988852ed9eabe3b5298d8b4c3b652e    I Never In My Life Gave A Guy No Money For Gas Or Food besides That Simpson Guy SMH I Fault Myself Though
```

From this data I want to extract sequential word patterns and save it into a bag. For example {i, never} would be the first and {never, in} would be the second and so on.
I know I would start the the program of with something like:

```
myinput = LOAD '/user/hive/warehouse/twitter_raw/$date' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (id,  mess);
strings = FOREACH myinput GENERATE $0 AS id, LOWER($1) AS mess;
```

But what would the next step be in this?

Comment: Johan, please refrain from using bad words. They have nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Sorry, didn't even look at the content of the string... It was taken at random from twitter.  Edit:Change the input string.

Answer (score 1):

Probably one can get the result by using only the built-in functions in a tricky way but a 
simple UDF will also do the job:

```
public class SlidingTuple extends EvalFunc<DataBag> {

    private static final BagFactory bagFactory = BagFactory.getInstance();
    private static final TupleFactory tupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();

    @Override
    public DataBag exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        try {
            DataBag inputBag = (DataBag) input.get(0);
            DataBag result = null;
            if (inputBag != null) {
                result = bagFactory.newDefaultBag();
                Iterator<Tuple> it = inputBag.iterator();
                Tuple previous = it.next();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Tuple current = it.next();
                    Tuple tuple = tupleFactory.newTuple(2);
                    tuple.set(0, previous.get(0));
                    tuple.set(1, current.get(0));
                    result.add(tuple);
                    previous = current;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("SlidingTuple error", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
A = LOAD '/user/hive/warehouse/twitter_raw/$date' USING PigStorage('\t') 
      AS (id:chararray,  mess:chararray);

B = foreach A generate TOKENIZE(mess, ' ') as words;
```

Then use your custom UDF:

```
C = foreach B generate com.example.SlidingTuple(words);
```

Comment: I ended up using a version of this after all since everything became much cleaner, and processing time is quite fast compared to my other approach, so thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @Johan: Great! Do you need any more help with this question?

Comment: No I modified your UDF and am now using it... I can't begin to express my gratification since this got me started on rewriting many perl scripts as UDFs. P.S. Wish I had the point to upvote your answer. D.S

Comment: @Johan I was over on Wikimedia Labs, noticed a bookmark to Github, then LinkedIn, then GoogleGroups for Datafu and saw your question was the most recent, read the thread. So here I am, and I saw that Lorand helped so I went ahead and up voted his answer since you said you wanted to but didn't have the points yet ;o) All is well!